# How to create demon process in cpp windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, process

There are steps to create demon process on linux platform.
But how to create demon process on windows using c++ language?

Comment: If you mean Windows Service - there is step by step example in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/writing-a-service-program-s-main-function)

Comment: @dewaffled - you should answer

Comment: Windows has a Service Control Manager so you don't have to resort to wild hacks like daemons.

Comment: I do not mean Windows Service.  I want to execute a c++ console application from command prompt.  This application turns itself as demon and returns the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Doc: [Windows services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/overview-of-windows-programming-in-cpp?view=msvc-160#windows-services)

> A Windows service is a program that can run in the background with
> little or no user interaction. These programs are called daemons on
> UNIX systems.

For more details about how to use services, I suggest you could refer to the Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/using-services

However, any Windows application can perform the role of a daemon, not just a service.

In Windows, return from the main function of an application results in a call to [ExitProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-exitprocess). All of the threads in the process, except the calling thread, terminate their executionit. If there are other threads running that should not be terminated, you should keep track of this and not exit from the main function until those threads are complete.

In practice, this means that all threads are "daemon threads".